# Get BASE_URL from SharedPreferences inside RetrofitClient

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, retrofit2

I want to fetch `BASE_URL` from SharedPreferences inside my `RetrofitClient` Class.

 My Code Is:
***RetrofitClient.java***:

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    private static final String BASE_URL = getBaseUrl();

    private String getBaseUrl() {
        SharedPreferences sp1 = getSharedPreferences("Login", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String apiUrl = sp1.getString("apiUrl", null);
        return apiUrl;
    }

    private RetrofitClient() {
        //MyRetrofitClient...
    }
}
```

How can i get get it work?

***MainActivity.java***:

```
Call<LoginResponse> call = RetrofitClient
            .getInstance()
            .getApi()
            .loginUser(username, password, action);

call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {

}
```

Comment: don't you need a context to `getSharedPreferences()` ?

Comment: Shared preferences require context of android component. You can't call it from simple java class.

Comment: @TejasPandya how can i pass Context to `RetrofitClient` class?

Answer (score 1):

For passing data , you need to make a constructor for that class . something like this

```
public class ApiClient {

Context my_conext;

  public ApiClient (Context context) {

        my_conext= context;
    }

 SharedPreferences sp1 = my_context.getSharedPreferences("Login", MODE_PRIVATE);

}
```

EDIT:  from your updated code .

you are doing it wrong .

first of all don't call function at the time of initialisation. use like this

```
 retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(getBaseUrl(my_context))
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
```

Second thing . you need `**Constructor**` constructor has the same name like class . carefully see my above answer . both has same name `ApiClient`. so in your case

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    Context my_conext;

      public RetrofitClient (Context context) {
            my_conext= context;
        }
    }
```

from activity , you are calling this `RetrofitClient` , call like this

```
   RetrofitClient(MainActivity.this).getApi();
```

Comment: I have already tried this, it says: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference`